# is there a servicebus solution where consumers don't consume events? (multiple consumers receive same event)

Tags: .net, php, messaging, producer-consumer, servicebus

I was reading up on ActiveMQ which seems like a great implementation of a servicebus where producers can post messages and other processes can receive them.

However when reading the documentation, it looks like the producer has to give the 'endpoint' when sending a message.

I would rather have it the other way around: My producer posts events 'import job starting', 'import job finished', etc
and any consumer which is interested in certain classes of events can subscribe and receive these. However the consumer should not consume the event in that it doesn't get send to other subscribers anymore.

What would be the best product to have this kind of property?

Constraints:
- It should have interfaces for at least .Net and php
- It should work across machine boundaries

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are currently publishing to a queue which typically means that 1 consumer would, well, consume the message and the event is handled. If you need to have more then 1 consumer receiving the events, you should use topics.

When using Topics, all subscribed consumers receive the event you have posted.

Take a look at this: http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html

Comment: Great! I would have never guessed such a feature would be called a topic. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the best, but I used [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) in project where was a task like yours. Check it's documentation.

References to implementations:

[C# implementation of D-Bus](http://www.ndesk.org/DBusSharp)

[Binding of PHP and DBus](http://code.google.com/p/php-dbus/)

I hope it wuill help.

Comment: If I read this correctly, this doesn't work across machine boundaries. I'll edit my original post to add this constraint

Comment: It work across machine boundaries. D-Bus can work over tcp/ip.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with having the service hosted on the cloud, [Microsoft's ServiceBus](http://msdn.com/sb) enables that scenario through it's Topic / Subscription model. Under this model, your producer sends a message to the Topic (a queue for all practical purposes), and anyone who's subscribed to it will get a copy of the message. For more advance scenarios, you can even create rules and filters to define which clients get which messages. There are both .NET and REST APIs for this.

You can check a full write up of the capabilities [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367516.aspx). The doc includes sample code on how to use the client libraries for this. There also [samples](http://servicebus.codeplex.com/releases/view/68709) on how to use servicebus with Java and PHP, in case you need support for those languages.